# jQuery Change picture on link click (matching with the same number in id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I got a generated list of links where every link has an unique id(number) and a class called "load".

I would like to change a picture on the other side of the page with the same number in the id as the link I clicked. Since id on elements are unique, i added folderid[number] infront of all the images

This is what i have so far (not working). I'm not sure if this is even close to correct but it feels like it :)

```
$(function(){
    $(".load").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var link_id = element.attr("id");
        alert(link_id);
        $("#folderid", link_id).attr("src", "img/folder_open.gif")
    });
});
```

My pictures and links looks like this in the code:

```
<img src="img/folder.gif" id="folderid5" class="img_folder" alt="Folder"/>
<a href="#" id="5" class="load img_id5">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you mean to select

```
$('#folderid' + link_id).attr(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live should do the trick for generated stuff.
Also: add a semicolon ( ; ) after attr(..., ...)

```
$("#folderid", link_id).attr("src", "img/folder_open.gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your images have their IDs as:

> folderid[1],folderid[2], etc

the '[' character is probably posing a problem with jQuery. You can try escaping it and using:

```
$("img#folderid\\["+link_id+"\\]").attr("src", "img/folder_open.gif");
```

I haven't had the need to escape characters in jQuery before, because I could simply change my naming convention, but I believe the above should work.

Another way to go would be to remove the brackets from the ID and use:

```
$("img#folderid"+link_id).attr("src", "img/folder_open.gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You need to concatenate the id onto the selector of the image instead of using a comma.  Try this code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".load").click(function(){
       var element = $(this);
         var link_id = element.attr("id");
        alert(link_id);
        $("#folderid" + link_id).attr("src", "img/folder_open.gif")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a + not a , on this line:

```
$("#folderid", link_id).attr("src", "img/folder_open.gif")
```

to

```
$("#folderid" + link_id).attr("src", "img/folder_open.gif")
```